# Controller's touchesBegan:withEvent: not triggered until the view's backgroundColor been set

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, events, uiviewcontroller

I discovered this weird things today when I try to build a demo app, basically I want my controller to do something when I touch the screen, so I wrote like below:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
      [super viewDidLoad];
      self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    //... do something here, but never called.
}
```

The touchesBegan method was never called. But after I set the `self.view.backgroundColor` property, the method was called as expected.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
      [super viewDidLoad];
      self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
      self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    //... called as expected
}
```

Did UIView never deliver any events if there is nothing to render? I'm I missing something here? any explanation is predicated.

Comment: did u touch your uiview?

Comment: ehhh...yeah of course I touched it, thx for reminding :-|

Comment: Just making a guess here: given that you have `self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;`, I gather that this is not the first controller that comes into view on start-up? What did you do before this controller gets loaded?